# 2 D Poisson - Unifrom distribution analysis

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, poisson-distribution

> Assume we have a box shaped area $(x,y)\in ([0,1],[0,1])$. There are $n$ kings $K_1, K_2,\cdots, K_n$ placed in this box randomly and independently according to uniform distribution. Enemies $E_1, E_2, \cdots$ are located in this area according to 2 dimensional Poisson point process with average $\mu$. Also, Queen is located at the point $(x,y)=(1,0.5)$. Show that for large enough $m$ 
>   $$E\left[\frac{1}{d_r^\alpha}\bigg| \frac{1}{d_r^{\alpha}}<m^{\alpha}\right] \leq \beta{ m^{2-\alpha}}$$
>   where $E[\cdot]$ is the expected value all possible locations of Kings and Enemies, $d_r$ is the distance between the closest enemy to the king $K_r$, $\alpha>2$, $\beta>0$, $m>0$.

I tried to solve this by first finding pdf of $d_r$ given $ \frac{1}{d_r^{\alpha}}<m^{\alpha}$, and then taking expectation. But, that is a huge mess. Any shortcuts? Any idea?

Comment: I don't know what the context of the question is, but it looks like the bound was calculated with Chebyshev's inequality: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff  Thanks for your comment. I have worked with Chebyshev a lot. But that is useful when you want to upper bound a probability. I am not sure how that can be applied to the expectation above. Can you clarify how generally it can be used to upper bound expectation?

Comment: @Michael Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Which PDF (or CDF) of $d_r$ did you find?